# Reading from a table and re-writing into another table with different structure using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

I am trying to read from a table with two columns--Customer No & Directors_name and writing to another table. the challenge is that a single customer number is tied to many directors in the 1st table with a maximum of 10 directors. I am to re-write this to another table to have a unique customer number and all the directors in a single row. table structure of the final table is Customer No, Director1, Director2, ....Director10. The tables are in an Oracle database.

Comment: no need to scream here

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: sounds like a pivot to me...

Comment: That's the requirement. U can help with any other way around it if you have one.

Comment: Simple fix with a `listagg`. OP doesn't even seem to have googled it.

Comment: @Rachcha, be kind to the OP. Google can be a big place and you will get lost if you don't know what you are looking for. This is why SO exists and a place for experts like you to help out us newbies. BTW, your answer should be placed in the answer section, not just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create or replace function addcolval(input in number) return varchar2  is
colval varchar2(32000);
begin
for c in (select Directors_Name from "your 2nd table" where Customer_No=input) loop
colval := colval||c.Directors_name||',';
end loop;
return rtrim(colval,',');
end;
```

and then

```
insert into "your 2nd table"(Customer_No) select distinct Customer_No from "your 1st table";
update "your 2nd table" as t1 set t1.Directors_Name =addcolval(t1.Customer_No);
```